# Combine Two Images with JavaScript for Watermark

Tags: javascript, html, image, watermark

I would like to combine two images (one uploaded from the device and another from the website) and export them as one image. The image uploaded from the device would be the background image and the one from the website is a logo to make in to a watermark in the bottom corner.

Is this possible and if so where should I start?
Thank you

Comment: HTML5 Canvas API

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283065/canvas-combing-two-images-return-one-img-html-object)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to add an image on top of another image using the Javascript code below:

```
function watermarkLogo(elemImage) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = elemImage.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = elemImage.naturalHeight;
    var myVar = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img1 = loadImage(elemImage.src, myFunction);
    var img2 = loadImage('icon.png', myFunction);

    var numberOfImages = 0;
    function myFunction() {
        numberOfImages += 1;

        if(numberOfImages == 2) {
            myVar.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
            myVar.globalAlpha = 0.5;

            var widthOffset = (canvas.width/3)*2;
            var heightOffset = (canvas.height/3)*2;

            myVar.drawImage(img2, widthOffset-50, heightOffset-50, 100, 100);
        }
    }

    function loadImage(src, onload) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = onload;
        img.src = src;
        return img;
    }
}
```