# How do I make two images into one image and change the color in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for a Youtuber, and I am making a character editor for him.

I am done with the editor itself, but now I want people to be able to save it as an image.
https://beretgang.github.io/red/editor is the link.
I made a beret and a face selector. The beret is an image that has #ededed as background, and the beret itself is transparent to be able to change the color.

Code RBB Slider:

```js
var hat = document.getElementById("editor-beret");
  var r = document.querySelector('#r');
  var g = document.querySelector('#g');
  var b = document.querySelector('#b');
  var r_out = document.querySelector('#r_out');
  var g_out = document.querySelector('#g_out');
  var b_out = document.querySelector('#b_out');

  function setColor(){
    var r_hex = parseInt(r.value, 10).toString(16),
        g_hex = parseInt(g.value, 10).toString(16),
        b_hex = parseInt(b.value, 10).toString(16),
        hex = "#" + pad(r_hex) + pad(g_hex) + pad(b_hex);
    hat.style.backgroundColor = hex;
  }

  function pad(n){
    return (n.length<2) ? "0"+n : n;
  }

  r.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    r_out.value = r.value;
  }, false);

  r.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    r_out.value = r.value;
  }, false);

  g.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    g_out.value = g.value;
  }, false);

  g.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    g_out.value = g.value;
  }, false);

  b.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    b_out.value = b.value;
  }, false);

  b.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    b_out.value = b.value;
  }, false);
```

```css
#editor-beret {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1) drop-shadow(0 0 0 black);
    filter: opacity(1) drop-shadow(0 0 0 black);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  fieldset{
    border: none;
  }
  output{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 2.5em;
  }
  label, output{
    padding: 2px 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  label[for=r], output[for=r]{
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  label[for=g], output[for=g]{
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  label[for=b], output[for=b]{
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  #editor-face {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<h3>Beret color:</h3>
      <img id="editor-beret" src="hat.png">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="r">R</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="r" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="r" id="r_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>  

      <fieldset>
        <label for="g">G</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="g" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="g" id="g_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="b">B</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="b" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="b" id="b_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>
```

(Don't run code snippet go to https://beretgang.github.io/red/editor) Based on answer:

```js
<script>
  var canvasObj = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvasObj.getContext("2d");
  var imgBeret = document.getElementById("editor-beret");
  var imgFace = document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection");
  var imgBeretNew = new Image; img.onload = draw; img.src = "https://beretgang.github.io/red/hat.png";
  var ctx = canvasObj.getContext("2d");
  
  var hat = document.getElementById("editor-beret");
  var r = document.querySelector('#r');
  var g = document.querySelector('#g');
  var b = document.querySelector('#b');
  var r_out = document.querySelector('#r_out');
  var g_out = document.querySelector('#g_out');
  var b_out = document.querySelector('#b_out');
  function setColor(){
    var r_hex = parseInt(r.value, 10).toString(16),
        g_hex = parseInt(g.value, 10).toString(16),
        b_hex = parseInt(b.value, 10).toString(16),
        hex = "#" + pad(r_hex) + pad(g_hex) + pad(b_hex);
    ctx.fillStyle = hex;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasObj.width, canvasObj.height);
    // set composite mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(imgBeretNew, 0, 0);
  }
  function pad(n){
    return (n.length<2) ? "0"+n : n;
  }
  r.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    r_out.value = r.value;
  }, false);
  r.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    r_out.value = r.value;
  }, false);
  g.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    g_out.value = g.value;
  }, false);
  g.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    g_out.value = g.value;
  }, false);
  b.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor();
    b_out.value = b.value;
  }, false);
  b.addEventListener('input', function() {
    setColor();
    b_out.value = b.value;
  }, false);
  
  
  
  function face1(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face1.png";
  }
  function face2(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face2.png";
  }
  function face3(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face3.png";
  }
  function face4(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face4.png";
  }
  function face5(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face5.png";
  }
  function face6(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face6.png";
  }
  function face7(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face7.png";
  }
  function face8(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face8.png";
  }
  function face9(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face9.png";
  }
  function face10(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face10.png";
  }
  function face11(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face11.png";
  }
  function face12(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face12.png";
  }
  function face13(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face13.png";
  }
  function face14(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face14.png";
  }
  function face15(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face15.png";
  }
  function face16(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face16.png";
  }
  function face17(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face17.png";
  }
  function face18(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face18.png";
  }
  function face19(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face19.png";
  }
  function face20(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face20.png";
  }
  function face21(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face21.png";
  }
  function face22(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face22.png";
  }
  function face23(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face23.png";
  }
  function face24(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face24.png";
  }
  function face25(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face25.png";
  }
  function face26(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face26.png";
  }
  function face27(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face27.png";
  }
  function face28(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face28.png";
  }
  function face29(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face29.png";
  }
  function face30(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face30.png";
  }
  function face31(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face31.png";
  }
  function face32(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face32.png";
  }
  function face33(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face33.png";
  }
  function face34(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face34.png";
  }
  function face35(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face35.png";
  }
  function face36(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face36.png";
  }
  function face37(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face37.png";
  }
  function face38(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face38.png";
  }
  function face39(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face39.png";
  }
  function face40(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face40.png";
  }
  function face41(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face41.png";
  }
  function face42(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face42.png";
  }
  function face43(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face43.png";
  }
  function face44(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face44.png";
  }
  function face45(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face45.png";
  }
  function face46(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face46.png";
  }
  function face47(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face47.png";
  }
  function face48(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face48.png";
  }
  function face49(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face49.png";
  }
  function face50(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face50.png";
  }
  function face51(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face51.png";
  }
  function face52(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face52.png";
  }
  function face53(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face53.png";
  }
  function face54(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face54.png";
  }
  function face55(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face55.png";
  }
  function face56(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face56.png";
  }
  function face57(){
    document.querySelector(".editor-face-selection").src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face57.png";
  }
</script>
```

```css
<style>
  * {
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
  ::selection {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }
  #nav {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  #nav h3 {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  #logo:hover {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  ul li.active a {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  ul li.active a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: none;
  }
  #btn {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ededed;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
  }
  #btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: #ededed;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    transform: scale(1.075);
  }
  center h1 {
    color: red;
  }
  #channel {
    color: white;
    background-color: #7289DA;
  }
  #editor-beret {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1) drop-shadow(0 0 0 black);
    filter: opacity(1) drop-shadow(0 0 0 black);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  fieldset{
    border: none;
  }
  output{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 2.5em;
  }
  label, output{
    padding: 2px 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  label[for=r], output[for=r]{
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  label[for=g], output[for=g]{
    background-color: #0f0;
  }
  label[for=b], output[for=b]{
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  #editor-face {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redberet - Editor</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" href="blogo.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Redberet's official website">
    <meta name="keywords" content="miracle,ide,coding,programming,code,program,software,download,informatics,ict,it">
    <meta name="author" content="Redberet official website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://beretgang.github.io/red/blogo.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ff0000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="nav">
          <a href="https://beretgang.github.io/red/"><img id="logo" src="blogo.png"></a>
          <h3>Redberet</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://beretgang.github.io/red/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
            <li><a href="smp-uhc">SMP and UHC</a></li>
            <li><a href="youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            <li><a href="discord">Discord</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="editor">Editor</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
      <h1>Character Editor</h1>
      <br>
      <h3>Beret color:</h3>
      <img id="editor-beret" src="hat.png">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="r">R</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="r" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="r" id="r_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>  

      <fieldset>
        <label for="g">G</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="g" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="g" id="g_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <label for="b">B</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="b" step="1" value="0">
        <output for="b" id="b_out">0</output>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <h3>Face:</h3>
      <img id="editor-face" class="editor-face-selection" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face1.png">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face1.png" onClick="face1();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face2.png" onClick="face2();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face3.png" onClick="face3();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face4.png" onClick="face4();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face5.png" onClick="face5();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face6.png" onClick="face6();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face7.png" onClick="face7();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face8.png" onClick="face8();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face9.png" onClick="face9();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face10.png" onClick="face10();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face11.png" onClick="face11();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face12.png" onClick="face12();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face13.png" onClick="face13();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face14.png" onClick="face14();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face15.png" onClick="face15();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face16.png" onClick="face16();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face17.png" onClick="face17();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face18.png" onClick="face18();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face19.png" onClick="face19();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face20.png" onClick="face20();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face21.png" onClick="face21();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face22.png" onClick="face22();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face23.png" onClick="face23();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face24.png" onClick="face24();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face25.png" onClick="face25();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face26.png" onClick="face26();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face27.png" onClick="face27();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face28.png" onClick="face28();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face29.png" onClick="face29();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face30.png" onClick="face30();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face31.png" onClick="face31();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face32.png" onClick="face32();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face33.png" onClick="face33();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face34.png" onClick="face34();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face35.png" onClick="face35();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face36.png" onClick="face36();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face37.png" onClick="face37();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face38.png" onClick="face38();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face39.png" onClick="face39();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face40.png" onClick="face40();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face41.png" onClick="face41();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face42.png" onClick="face42();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face43.png" onClick="face43();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face44.png" onClick="face44();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face45.png" onClick="face45();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face46.png" onClick="face46();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face47.png" onClick="face47();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face48.png" onClick="face48();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face49.png" onClick="face49();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face50.png" onClick="face50();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face3.png" onClick="face3();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face52.png" onClick="face52();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face53.png" onClick="face53();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face3.png" onClick="face3();"></button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face55.png" onClick="face55();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face56.png" onClick="face56();"></button>   <button><img id="editor-face" src="https://beretgang.github.io/red/faces/face3.png" onClick="face3();"></button>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the background and fill in the beret with the color selected. 
I also want to save the image with the beret + the face. But how do I do that?

Comment: Do you want the user to download the final image or send it to the server?

Comment: The user to download it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render an image in Javascript, the best solution would be to use a canvas. Those, you can export and you can combine images easily in canvases. Maybe, this question will help you: [Canvas - Combing two images, return one img html object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283065/canvas-combing-two-images-return-one-img-html-object)

Another solution would be to process images on your server. If you use PHP for example, you can combine images with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I will use Sylens's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a canvas to do this. You can render both the images onto a canvas like this:

```
  var canvasObj = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvasObj.getContext("2d");
  var imgBeret = document.getElementById("idOfBeretImage");
  var imgFace = document.getElementById("idOfFace");
  ctx.drawImage(imgBeret, 10, 10); // you will have to position 
  ctx.drawImage(imgFace, 10, 10); // you will have to position
```

It's a good idea to use the beret image with a transparent background, you can keep the white colour inside the beret, and transparent outside so that it will seamlessly be rendered on the canvas.

More info on drawing on the canvas: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage

To save the canvas to an Image or to Download that image, we can use this library. **Canvas2image**

With the following code we can get an image out of the canvas:

```
Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvasObj, width, height, type)
```

More info on the library: https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

Comment: But how can I change the color of the beret with the white back colour inside the beret and transparent outside?

Comment: You could use a photo editor like Photoshop to do that, and make a PNG image.

Comment: But how do I make it change the color with the RGB slider?

Comment: I edited my post so now it also shows the RGB slider code to help you

Comment: does this help with the coloring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706829/change-color-image-in-canvas

You can do this and then draw the face image to the canvas

Comment: I did a combination of your two things and it made the beret stop working, I edited the post and it now shows `based on your answer:`. Look at that, that is the code.